# Trying to add a warning to prevent users from leaving a form before submitting. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript

I have looked on here and around the internet for over 5 hours and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. It is probably something really simple. Here is my code so far:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.addEvent('load', function() {
document.getElementsByClassName('submitformlisting')[0].onclick = function(){
window.btn_clicked = true;
};
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
if(!window.btn_clicked){
    return 'If you leave now, your information will be lost.';
}
};
});//]]>  

</script>
```

And my submit button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitformlisting" class="id="submitformlisting"" value="Add Listing" tabindex="4" onclick="return doSubmit();" />
```

Comment: Always precise, when asking, what exactly doesn't work and what are the errors in the console (you [checked the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console), right ?).

Comment: The errro in the console is: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'addEvent'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You messed the class in your html. Change `class="id="submitformlisting""` to `class="submitformlisting"`.

But you'd better use the id instead of the class.

Change

```
document.getElementsByClassName('submitformlisting')[0].onclick = function(){
```

to

```
document.getElementById('submitformlisting').onclick = function(){
```

Comment: I made these changes and it still isn't working. The onbeforeunload warning isn't being triggered. It is acting like the whole javascript doesn't exist.